# Series of conditional foreachs not executing neo4j cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am trying to use a **FOREACH** for a conditional statement. I am passing in a parameter **$hasLegs** and if the value is equal to **'Y'** I perform a **MERGE**. However, this does not seem to want to execute since the entire operation is bypassed and not run.

I have tried the **FOREACH** method, using **APOC** and using **WITH** but no luck so far. Maybe it is just not my week.

Foreach Example:

```
MERGE (species:Species {name: $name})
  ON CREATE SET species.GUID = apoc.create.uuid(), species.creationDate = datetime()

WITH species
with species, $hasLegs as hasLegs
FOREACH (ignore IN CASE WHEN $hasLegs = 'Y' THEN [1] ELSE [] END | MERGE (species)-[:LINKS_TO]->(:Question:Root{type: 'Legs'}) )

RETURN species
```

APOC Example

```
MERGE (species:Species {name: $name})
  ON CREATE SET species.GUID = apoc.create.uuid(), species.creationDate = datetime()
WITH species
MATCH (l:Question:Root{type: 'Legs')
CALL apoc.when(hasLegs='Y', 'MERGE (species)-[:LINKS_TO]->(l)','', { l:l, species: species }) YIELD value
WITH value AS ignored, species
RETURN species
```

The expected output is just, with the parameters: **$name**, **$hasLegs**.

**$name** is a **MERGE** to prevent duplicate nodes, however **$hasLegs** is either equal to **'Y'** or **null**.

(species)-[:LINK_TO]->(question)

Any help is greatly appreciated! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your query seems to be working fine, the use of for each is correct.

However it will create new `Question` node each time it is executed. To use unique Question node use 2 `MERGE` clauses:

```
MERGE (q:Question:Root{type: 'Legs'}) MERGE (species)-[:LINKS_TO]->(q)
```

Whole query:

```
MERGE (species:Species {name: $name})
  ON CREATE SET species.GUID = apoc.create.uuid(), species.creationDate = datetime()
WITH species
with species, $hasLegs as hasLegs
FOREACH (ignore IN CASE WHEN $hasLegs = 'Y' THEN [1] ELSE [] END | MERGE (q:Question:Root{type: 'Legs'}) MERGE (species)-[:LINKS_TO]->(q) )
RETURN species
```